# atop shows queue depth is higher than maximum

Tags: linux, io, atop

In my `atop` logs, I see `avq` ("average queue depth") over 600.  This is on an LVM Logical Volume (LV).  Both the LV and the physical volume have `nr_requests` (maximum queue depth) of 128.

(Note, to see `avq` in `atop`, I reduce my terminal font size (View->Zoom out).  This gives `atop` enough space to show all the statistics it knows about).

It is not possible to write to the maximum queue depth on the LV.  So I don't know if the maximum queue depth on the LV does anything.  But I expect there is some limit on the queue depth... and that it would not be over 600!

This log sample is from a time when the system was under stress, and not very responsive.  So I am trying to analyse it... but it's not clear whether I can trust this particular data point.

What does it mean?  Is `atop` showing a wrong or misleading figure?  Is the kernel doing something wrong?  Could the kernel be working as designed, and there's an explanation I don't know about?

The system is Fedora Workstation 28.  I don't remember doing any IO tuning.  My `atop` version is `2.3.0-10.fc28.x86_64`, and the kernel is `4.18.16-200.fc28.x86_64`.

---

`LVM | ll_2016-swap  | busy  59% |  read   24328 | write 175735 | KiB/r   4 | KiB/w    4 | MBr/s   0.2 | MBw/s   1.1 |`**`avq   684.13`**`|  avio 1.76 ms`

`DSK |          sda  | busy  93% |  read   88967 | write  45808 | KiB/r  81 | KiB/w  152 | MBr/s  11.8 | MBw/s  11.4 | avq    96.50 |  avio 4.12 ms`

```
$ lsblk
NAME                      MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                         8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk 
├─sda1                      8:1    0   500M  0 part /boot/efi
~
└─sda7                      8:7    0 371.4G  0 part 
  ├─alan_dell_2016-fedora 253:0    0    40G  0 lvm  /
  ├─alan_dell_2016-swap   253:1    0     2G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
  └─alan_dell_2016-home   253:2    0   303G  0 lvm  /home

$ cat /sys/block/dm-1/dm/name
alan_dell_2016-swap

$ cat /sys/block/dm-1/queue/nr_requests
128
$ cat /sys/block/sda/queue/nr_requests
128

$ echo 4 | sudo tee /sys/block/dm-1/queue/nr_requests
4
tee: /sys/block/dm-1/queue/nr_requests: Invalid argument
$ cat /sys/block/dm-1/queue/nr_requests
128

$ echo 4 | sudo tee /sys/block/sda/queue/nr_requests
4
$ cat /sys/block/sda/queue/nr_requests
4
$ cat /sys/block/dm-1/queue/nr_requests
128
```