# How to find max queue length for device?

Tags: partition, disk, io, load, iostat

Recently I ran into some I/O overload problrms on some of our machines and I have been searching to find thresholds for some metrics like:

```
avgqu-sz  
await  
svctm
```

Then I saw this post on Stack Overflow:
[display current I/O](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13613550/how-do-i-display-the-current-disk-io-queue-length-on-linux)

I wonder if there is any way to find max queue length of my machine so when `avgqu-sz` is more than that number it means overload occurred?

Does queue length depends on RAID?

Comment: `svctm` is complete junk.  See `man iostat` or https://utcc.utoronto.ca/~cks/space/blog/linux/IostatProblems

Comment: equal to (or approaching) - a value cannot be larger than a maximum.  the absolute maximum is supposed to be calculated from the field `nr_requests`. though recently there are also a couple of features that can dynamically throttle it down. and there is some [weirdness](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/479717/atop-shows-queue-depth-is-higher-than-maximum) that i do not understand.